# Python code recursion: how many compilation you can get of number as sum, but I don't get how I can print this compilation

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, recursion, sum

Python code recursion: this code gives you how many compilation you can get of number as sum of list (ex: n=4 list=[1,2] the result is 5 ways), but I don't get how I can print this compilation, anyone for help? ( 1+1+1+1 , 1+1+2 , 1+2+1 , 2+1+1 , 2+2)

```
def count_many_times(n,lst):
    ''' func count how many combination we can make '''
    if n==0:
        return 1
    if n<0:
        return 0
    counter=0
    for num in lst:
        ''' this loop checks which number can bring me the n number by adding'''
        counter += count_many_times(n-num,lst)
    return counter

def string_to_int():
    ''' convert string to int '''
    st_int = [int(x) for x in input().split(' ')]
    return st_int

def main():
    lst=[]
    sub_lst = string_to_int()
    while sub_lst[0] != 0: # this loop goes until we find 0
        lst.append(sub_lst)
        sub_lst = string_to_int()
    
    for i in lst: 
        for j in i: 
            n=i[0] # take first number
            num_parts=list(i[1:]) # take the other like alist to calculate combination
            x = count_many_times(n,num_parts) # function give me num of combination
        print(x)
main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the current compilation at each recursive call and when you hit the base case `n==0`, i.e. a compilation successfully found, then you can print the current compliation.

```py
def count_many_times(n,lst,compilation=[]):
    ''' func count hoy many combination we can make '''
    if n==0:
        print(compilation)
        return 1
    if n<0:
        return 0
    counter=0
    for num in lst:
        ''' this loop check wich number can bring me the n number by adding'''
        counter += count_many_times(n-num,lst,compilation+[num])
    return counter

print(count_many_times(4,[1,2]))
```

---

Output

```
[1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 1]
[2, 1, 1]
[2, 2]
5
```

Comment: im new here so if you can tell me also how i mark it as solved qustion

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.